# VMware ESXi4.1Update1 and Raid6 Raw drive (>2TB) for VM

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi

I´ve an raid6 array with data and would like to migrate the server to ESXi 4.1Update1

So the system partition is already a vmdk and the OS is running on an esxi guest already fine - but without the data storage.

```
/vmfs/volumes/4da9bcb7-d393d0d0-ed52-00151746360d # fdisk -l

Disk /dev/disks/eui.0004d92784c7d800: 5999.9 GB, 5999999582208 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 729458 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

                       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/disks/eui.0004d92784c7d800p1             1         1        16+  ee  EFI GPT
/dev/disks/eui.0004d92784c7d800p2   *         1    267350 2147483647+  8e  Linux LVM


/vmfs/volumes/4da9bcb7-d393d0d0-ed52-00151746360d # vmkfstools -z /vmfs/devices/disks/eui.0004d92784c7d800 /vmfs/volumes/4da9bcb7-d393d0d0-ed52-00151746360d/FS-DISK2.vmdk -a lsilogic
Failed to create virtual disk: The destination file system does not support large files (12).
/vmfs/volumes/4da9bcb7-d393d0d0-ed52-00151746360d # vmkfstools -r /vmfs/devices/disks/eui.0004d92784c7d800 /vmfs/volumes/4da9bcb7-d393d0d0-ed52-00151746360d/FS-DISK2.vmdk -a lsilogic
Failed to create virtual disk: The destination file system does not support large files (12).
```

so maybe anyone can help me or any suggestion?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Can you please edit your question and clarify what it is that you need help with?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but as a new user to this site you're going to have to do better with your questions in the future if you wish to get the best out of the site and contribute to it - I can kind of see your question but it's far from clear.

Now on to your actual question; am I right in assuming that you want to create a >2TB single .vmdk? if so then you can't, you can present multiple 2TB .vmdk's to the OS and have that bind them together somehow (LVM for Linux or via disk manager in Windows, you don't mention an OS).
ESX/ESXi can't create a VMFS3 partition larger than 2TB but can create a datastore of up to 32 x 2TB VMFS partitions, but as stated before can't create a >2TB .vmdk, nor can you pass a >2TB RDM through to a VM.

If we've mistaken the intent of your question please feel free to add more detail.

Comment: ok, i dont want to create a vmdk greater than 2TB, on the actual "Disc" /dev/disks/eui.0004d92784c7d800: 5999.9 GB, 5999999582208 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 729458 cylinders Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes there are two partitions from my old server structure - no virtualisation. Know i want to create a virtualisation platform but donw want to touch the 6TB "disc" so i´ve a single sata drive where i install ESXi4.1, in vmware i´ve created a new VM with my "old" server OS which works fine but it cant access the 6TB "Storage disc", pci passthrougt wont work, no VT-d

Comment: See "nor can you pass a >2TB RDM through to a VM" from above - can't be done sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in the SCSI protocol, you can't have single LUNs larger than 2Tb - 512bytes.
Split your disk group in to smaller logical disks (~1.9Tb each).

Comment: *psst* it is a limitation but of VMFS3 not SCSI ;)

Comment: You may want to read http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=3371739

Comment: That's a limitation of ESX/ESXi's use of SCSI-2 and Read (10), SCSI provides Read (12), Read (16) and Read (32) in newer variants - it's VMFS3's use of this that is the limit, no SCSI per se. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_Read_Commands

Comment: i cant because the 6TB volume is already full with data and works fine with non virtualisation OS (Debian)

Comment: perhaps you should have read the documentation or got some training first?